# Understanding what these reference shortforms represent

Tags: literature

In the book ["Giordano BRUNO His Life and Thought" by Dorothea Waley Singer, chapter 7](http://www.positiveatheism.org/hist/bruno07f.htm)  references often have a form of

```
18 Doc. Ven. XV.
```

or

```
49 Docc. Rom. XX, XXI.
```

How do I decipher their meaning?

Comment: This isn't a History question at all. I'd suggest trying English.se.

Comment: Working with historical sources is not a history? Oh my God, where this world goes???